# Error after updating Blazor WASM Project - Conflicting assets with the same path '/wwwroot/_content

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I just updated a project with all new microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly(s).. v5.0.10 from v5.0.5.  Now when I recompile I get the following error:
[image]

I've search everywhere and cannot find anymore reference to v5.0.5, only 5.0.10 and cannot find /wwwroot/_content either.

Any help/guidance is much appreciated.
Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Tried closing VS. deleting all the .vs bin and obj folders in the solution projects?

Comment: Thanks Brian for the quick response!  Worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

By default, there's no reason for an RCL file to conflict with a file on the host. RCL files are prefixed with _content/${PackageId}. Blazor WebAssembly files are placed at the root of the host URL space, which makes conflicts easier. For example, Blazor WebAssembly apps contain a favicon.ico file that the host might also include in its wwwroot folder.

If the conflict's source is an RCL file, it often means code is copying assets from the library into the project's wwwroot folder. Writing code to copy files defeats a primary goal of static web assets. This goal is fundamental to get updates on the browser when the contents are updated without having to trigger a new compilation.

You may choose to preserve this behavior and maintain the file on the host. To do so, remove the file from the list of static web assets with a custom MSBuild target.

To use the RCL's file or the Blazor WebAssembly app's file instead of the host project's file, remove the file from the host project.

[Microsoft Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/5.0/blazor-static-web-assets-validation-logic-updated)